# How minimize python3.7 application docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, pyinstaller

I would like to dockerize python program with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY requirements.pip ./requirements.pip

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -U setuptools

RUN apk update

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev g++ && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.pip --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps

ARG APP_DIR=/app

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR} 

WORKDIR ${APP_DIR} 

COPY app . 

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "run.py" ]
```

and this is my `requirements.pip` file:

```
pysher~=0.5.0

redis~=2.10.6

flake8~=3.5.0

pandas==0.23.4
```

Because of pandas, the docker image has 461MB, without pandas 131MB.

I was thinking how to make it smaller, so I build binary file from my applicaiton using:

```
pyinstaller run.py --onefile
```

It build 38M binary file. When I run it, it works fine. So I build docker image from `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

ARG APP_DIR=/app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

COPY app/dist/run run

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/app/run" ]
```

Basicaly, just copied my `run` binary file into `/app` directory. It looks fine, image has just 48.8MB. When I run the container, I receive error:

```
$ docker run --rm --name myapp myminimalimage:latest
/app/run: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Then I was thinking, maybe there is problem with `sh`, so I installed `bash`, so I added 3 lines into `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apk update

RUN apk upgrade

RUN apk add bash
```

Image was built, but when I run it there is error again:

```
$ $ docker run --rm --name myapp myminimalimage:latest
/app/run: /app/run: cannot execute binary file
```

My questions:

1. Why is the image in the first step so big? Can I minimize the size
   somehow ? Like choose what to install from pandas package?
2. Why is my binary file working fine on my system (Kubuntu 18.10) but I
       cant run it from `alpine:3.4`, should I use another image or install
       something to run it?
3. What is the best way to build minimalistic image with my app? One of
       mentioned above or is there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

On sizes, make sure you *always* pass `--no-cache-dir` when using `pip` (you use it once, but not in other cases). Similarly, combine uses of `apk` and make sure the last step is to clear the `apk` cache so it never gets frozen in an image layer, e.g. replace your three separate `RUN`s with `RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`; achieves the same effect in a single layer, that doesn't keep the `apk` cache around.

Example:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY requirements.pip ./requirements.pip

# Avoid pip cache, use consistent command line with other uses, and merge simple layers
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir setuptools

# Combine update and add into same layer, clear cache explicitly at end
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev g++ && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.pip --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Don't expect it to do much (you already used `--no-cache-dir` on the big `pip` operation), but it's something. `pandas` is a huge monolithic package, dependent on other huge monolithic packages; there is a limit to what you can accomplish here.

Comment: Thanks, it get from 461M to 393M. Pandas take approximately 300M in image, when I built it without pandas. Why I am able to build functional binary executable using `pyinstaller` and have only 38M file and 48.8M docker image?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you don't use Alpine, you won't need a compiler, since you can just use wheels. This makes everything simpler... e.g. you don't need to install and then uninstall compilers. Slightly bigger, but only slightly.

(See here for more about why I'm not a fan of Alpine Linux: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/)

Comment: I have to install compiler because pandas needs it. I was unable to build image without that. Do you know why I am not able to run executable from alpine?

Comment: pandas won't need a compiler if your base image is `python:3.7-slim-buster`.